# Blackberry Android Lauch doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-android

I'm trying to debug a ported android application on my Blackberry Playbook, but it gives me this error whenever I try to launch it as a `Blackberry Android Launch`:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching The Dot Game Playbook".
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper.parseForData(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;)Lcom/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData;
```

I can't figure out what's causing this error. The app runs fine in the android emulator, but won't work with the blackberry tools. I've tried cleaning the project, updating the android SDK, restarting Eclipse, and reinstalling the Blackberry plugins, but nothing's worked. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.g33kworld.thedotgame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name="net.g33kworld.thedotgame.DotGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Perhaps the debug token on the device has expired. Have you checked it?

Comment: I created the debug token when I started trying to test it. I just checked it, it expires on December 12.

Comment: Hm. What's in your manifest file?

Comment: What happens if you change the target sdk version from 15 to 10?

Comment: Oh, I see that you edited the post. Was the target 10 all along? Also, I assume that the apk passed the compatibility tests with flying colors?

Comment: No, I just noticed that and changed it. I did a clean and build, but it gave me the same error so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Can you run the app on the BB simulator?

Comment: Oh, I think the min sdk version also needs to be 10.

Comment: I tried changing it, no luck. Also, it passed the online compatibility test with no errors. The online packager works fine, too.

Comment: The only other thing I'd suggest is to try running it with the command line tools or with the BlackBerry Graphical Aid or the DDPB installer tools. (Anything outside of Eclipse.) Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It worked fine when I compiled  it with the [Blackberry Online Packager](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) and installed it with DDPB, but I'd like to know how to get Eclipse working (since debugging will be a real pain this way).

Comment: I have the same issue. I mention one thing - in Debug Configuration on 'Project' tab there in no activity to specify as launch activity. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: When I try to open the debug configuration, I get the error: `An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper.parseForData(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;)Lcom/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlackBerry Plug-in 1.3 Beta is not compatible with ADT (Android Development Tools) version 21. I also experienced this bug on both Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.7.5.

After an hour I finally found a solution (workaround):

1. Uninstall ADT and BlackBerry plug-in from Eclipse
2. Manually download ADT 20 from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip)
3. Install ADT as Eclipse plug-in from the downloaded archive
4. Install BlackBerry plug-in 1.3 Beta

Please note that I have also posted the solution with more details at my [personal site](https://www.anavi.org/article/152/)

Comment: Yes, I've heard that this is the problem from a few other places now as well. I think I'll just use the command-line tools and wait for the next release of the plugin rather than downgrading ADT.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install beta version of BB plugin for eclipse? please refer this [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Problem-when-launching-an-app-in-simulator-with-Eclipse/m-p/1815075/highlight/true#M2558) for more.